# Why MEF-container isn't available in modules?

Tags: prism, mef, containers

In my Prism app, the MEF container is available from within the Bootstrapper class via the Container property.

But it isn't from within the class module (IModule). I may only import the container through IServiceLocator.

Why? I thought that it made sense to use a common interface against concrete technology, but the Prism 4.1 guideline ask us to not use IServiceLocator (in [Considerations for Using IServiceLocator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921140%28v=pandp.40%29#sec12)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it corresponds not to Prism or MEF, but to Dependency Injection principle and best practices in general. (Yeah, I knot that MEF isn't DI container, but here it's used almost as DI container, so I suppose to use the same practices here).

In best practices of DI ([this](http://manning.com/seemann/) book is very cool, I highly recommend it) it's good to have such steps in DI "workflow":

- register all necessary types (in Prism - by Bootstrapper.ConfigureCatalog() method)
- resolve root object (with all nested objects. In Prism - by Bootstrapper.CreateShell() method)
- use your root object
- release you root object

Ideally, you should NOT use DI container anymore. Your code should NOT know about existance of DI container (from this side Unity is really DI container, because you can write code which will not know about using DI container). If your code knows about it - it DEPENDS on DI container, and it's bad thing.

PS. If you want to use MEF container in your module anyway (for example, because you're not very familiar with DI paradigm or you have some very specific tasks), you can try something like:

```
[ModuleExport(typeof(YourModule))]
public class YourModule : IModule
{
    public static CompositionContainer CompositionContainer;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public void YourModule(CompositionContainer container)
    {
        this.CompositionContainer = container;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to register your MEF container itself in your Boostrapper:

```
public class YourBootstrapper: MefBootstrapper
{
    protected override CompositionContainer CreateContainer()
    {
        var container = base.CreateContainer();
        container.ComposeExportedValue(container);
        return container;
    }
}
```

Comment: while i agree with the best practices, the prism documentation clearly states that you can use the Initialize method of your method  as well to "Register shared services with the application's dependency injection container." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405479%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx

Comment: If we're not supposed to know about the container, then how can modules register new shared services?

Comment: The mentioned `ComposeExportedValue` is an extention method in `System.ComponentModel.Composition.AttributedModelServices`

Answer (score 0):

Note that I am using an older version of Prism and that I am using it with the UnityContainer but that same principles should apply.

Define your Module class to take a container in the constructor.

Here is an example using Unity:

```
public class Module : IModule
{
    public static IUnityContainer Container;

    public Module(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        Container = container;
    }
}
```

If you define a constructor which takes a container, it will get called by the ApplicationBootstrapper.Run() method.

I tested with a default parameter-less constructor and an overload constructor which takes the container and the second constructor was called.

I also checked with having only the default constructor and it got called. I would suggest you change your constructor to add a parameter taking a container.

Having a container in your module class will allow you to register types in your Initialize method.

As for ServiceLocator, that's a slightly different pattern that I would recommend you use in instances where you cannot get your dependencies created by the container for some reason.

Comment: I was trying to do that. MEF use CompositionContainer type instead of Unity's IUnityContainer. But my constructor with parameter typed CompositionContainer not executing.

Comment: @reito: Do you also have a default constructor and how do you call the ApplicationBootstrapper run method ?

Comment: I have no constructors anymore, only this one.
The Bootstrapper Run method is calling within OnStartup method of my Application class.